# Regex to accept 3 out of 4 rules

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, match, special-characters

I can't seem to get the regex correct for the following requirement: a string between 8 and 20 length that must contain at least 1 uppercase alphabet character, at least 1 lowercase alphabet character, and either at least 1 digit or at least 1 special character (or both).  Let's say special characters are restricted to include just @,#,&,~.

I wrote this initially:

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=(.*?[0-9])|(.*?[@#&~])).{8,20}$
```

So as expected it successfully matches strings like 5abcdefG, Abc@defghi, 5abcdefG~, etc.

The problem is it allows characters OTHER than the 4 special ones I mentioned.  So strings like 1€abcdefG and Abc!defghi also match, but they shouldn't.  What am I missing?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9@#&~]*[0-9@#&~])[A-Za-z0-9@#&~]{8,20}$`. Note that `.` matches any char but a newline.

Comment: ab4cdefG@ does not match, but should...

Comment: You should provide test data

Comment: Like?  Provided examples above...

Comment: Try following regexp: http://www.regexr.com/3dltf

Comment: By the way, if this is for passwords, you *want* to allow characters you didn't anticipate. This will increase the entropy and make it more difficult for an attacker to brute force the hash.

Comment: @HoneyBradger: You must have copied the regex from the comment, SO introduces weird invisible chars inside comments. Try copying from the [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nU6nO8/1) or from my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that your `.` matches any char but a newline, so it can match a lot of characters other than your 4 special chars, letters or digits.

Also, it makes no sense to split *OR* condition into 2 alternative branches with lookaheads (`(?=(.*?[0-9])|(.*?[@#&~]))`). You can merge that condition into a single `(?=.*?[0-9@#&~])`. The point is that the ranges/chars inside the positive character class are "OR'ed", `[0-9@#&~]` matches either a digit, or `@`, or `#`, or `&`, or `~`.

I suggest

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^0-9@#&~]*[0-9@#&~])[A-Za-z0-9@#&~]{8,20}$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nU6nO8/1)

You may also use comment mode or blocks to build a dynamic pattern to make the pattern readable and maintainable:

```
^                           # start of string
  (?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])          # string must have an uppercase letter
  (?=[^a-z]*[a-z])          # string must have a lowercase letter
  (?=[^0-9@#&~]*[0-9@#&~])  # string must have a digit or defined special char
  [A-Za-z0-9@#&~]{8,20}     # The string should have 8 to 20 symbols from the defined set
$                           # end of string
```

The `[A-Za-z0-9@#&~]` will only allow letters, digits, and special chars you specify in this character class.

This regex also conforms to the principle of contrast (lookaheads fail or match quicker with negated character classes).

Comment: @HoneyBradger says it doesn't work, but it definitely does. https://regex101.com/r/cZ3lX8/1

Comment: Don't enable this kind of horrible design. -1

Comment: @jpmc: Downvoting **working solution** because *you* do not like it is meaningless.

Comment: It's not a question of me not liking it. It's a question of trying to maintain the thing. It would take anyone 20 minutes just to figure out what this does, and anyone trying to modify it is more likely to break it than anything. This question itself proves that much.

Comment: If you insist, I can be specific and say "the average developer." Regardless, downvoting because the answer is difficult to maintain is a *completely* valid use of downvotes.

Comment: It is not difficult, see the update. Also, a password validation technique with regex is [well known](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#password).

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer here is *don't use a single regex*. This will simplify everything:

- 8 to 20 characters: Every language provides a standard way fetching the string length. Use it and just check the number.
- Contains an uppercase letter: Check that it matches `[A-Z]`. You may need to modify this for internationalization.
- Contains a lowercase letter: Check that it matches `[a-z]`. You may need to modify this for internationalization.
- Contains a digit: Check that it matches `[0-9]`.
- Contains a special character: Check that it matches `[@#&~]`.
- Consists of only allowed characters: Make it match `^[A-Za-z0-9@#&~]+$`. (This seems like a dubious requirement, especially if this is for passwords.)

You'll have some extra conditionals around the last two checks to require only one, but that isn't a big deal.

The bottom line is that no one will be able to read a single regex for this. You'll have to document everything that it does, and every developer who touches that regex will either hate you or re-implement it as multiple checks like I've described here. **Stop**. Seriously. This is "parse HTML with regex" level of bad design. Just use multiple checks. It is the most sane approach.

Most importantly, it will be much easier to add new requirements later on, and you'll have to do it anyway if you run into something that isn't possible to check via regex.